# How to use Ruby's pp to format a string?

Tags: ruby

I am trying to use the `pp` format algorithm to print to a logger. I think that this is possible since I have done it in the past.

I can do something like

```
require 'stringio'

def pp_to_string(obj)
  io = StringIO.new

  pp(obj, io)
  io.string
end

logger.info(pp_to_string(my_obj))
```

But it feels pretty convoluted.

Is there a way to do it in a cleaner way?

Comment: Maybe it will work as a class method `PP.pp(my_obj)`

Comment: I've tried that and it doesn't work since the pp class method returns an IO.

Comment: Found the answer (`pretty_inspect`); the question was asked before. Closing as duplicate. It's still a good question, as it's not documented very well.